# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER

Tags: java, android, android-studio, post, retrofit

Busque en todos los posts acerca de este error y ninguno habla de mi problemática. Me explico:

Estoy haciendo una app con la versión más reciente de Android Studio (es mi segunda app por lo que aún no sé muchas cosas aún de Android Studio), y esa app consume de una API sus métodos GET y POST (hasta el momento no tenemos necesidad de usar los demás). Los métodos GET los consumo sin ningún problema, la app se conecta y descarga la información de manera correcta. Mi problemática viene al tratar de enviar la información con el método POST.

No sé si esté bien hecho lo que traté de hacer, se los pongo abajo para ver si ustedes detectan algo fuera de lo normal...

Esta es mi interface:

```
@POST("PruebaGP")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<EnviarUno> postUno(
    @Field("Nombre") String Nombre,
    @Field("FecUpdate") String FecUpdate
);
```

esta es mi clase EnviarUno:

```
public class EnviarUno {
    public String Nombre;
    public String FecUpdate;

    public EnviarUno(String Nombre, String FecUpdate) {
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
        this.FecUpdate = FecUpdate;
    }
}
```

y así lo consumo:

```
String sNombre = "Pipo";
String sFecha = "2022-04-30 10:08:00";
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://www.fletesmex.com.mx/APITEST/api/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(okhttpclient)
    .build();
API api = retrofit.create(API.class);
Call<EnviarUno> call = api.postUno(sNombre, sFecha);
call.enqueue(new Callback<EnviarUno>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<EnviarUno> call, Response<EnviarUno> response) {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Conectado pero con error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Información enviada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<EnviarUno> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

El problema al que me enfrento es que, al hacer la conexión con la API, la respuesta de ésta  me la manda en el onFailure:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 2 path $

**peeeero sí inserta los datos en la tabla...**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la estructura de mi tabla (no sé si tenga algo que ver pero la pongo por cualquier cosa):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buscando en la web también traté de hacerlo de la siguiente manera, modificando mi interfaz y la forma en que la invocaba, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
API api = retrofit.create(API.class);
EnviarUno enviaruno = new EnviarUno (sNombre, sFecha);
Call<EnviarUno> call = api.postUno(enviaruno);
call.enqueue(new Callback<EnviarUno>() {...}
```

```
@POST("PruebaGP")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<EnviarUno> postUno(@Body EnviarUno enviaruno);
```

Pero el error es el mismo...

¿Alguien sabe que está mal?

Gracias por su apoyo!

Comment: Todo se llama Prueba o Test porque cree ese proyecto para tratar de comprender como funciona Retrofit y luego ya replicarlo en la aplicación final. Gracias por su atención!

Comment: Has intentado cambiando la forma de recibir el Call de retrofit de Call<EnviarUno> a tipo String de esta forma: Call<String> tanto en el Interface como en la llamada para consumirlo?

Comment: El mensaje de error te lo está diciendo claro: *`Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was NUMBER at line 1 column 2`*, lo que ocurre es que **la API no te está devolviendo un objeto válido**, que debería ser algo que empiece por`{... objeto válido}` o por `[...objeto válido]` sino que te está devolviendo un objeto mal formado, que tiene un número antes de `{ }` o de `[]`. Depura la respuesta de la API y verás el problema. Si es una API tuya, comparte el código que gestiona esa petición y podremos decirte cuál es el problema, pues no es un problema de Android, sino de la API (servidor).

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas y sus comentarios!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya está ese detalle, ya no entra en el OnFailure. El problema es que no pasaba un Objeto Json como tal, quedó de la siguiente forma por si alguien tiene la misma situación.

En la clase del MainActivity quedó así:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Callback<EnviarUno> {...}
```

El envío de datos quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
public void EnviarDatos(View view) {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://www.fletesmex.com.mx/APITEST/api/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
    API api = retrofit.create(API.class);
    try {
        JSONObject paramObject = new JSONObject();
        paramObject.put("IdRow", "1");
        paramObject.put("Nombre", "Pruebita tablet");
        paramObject.put("FecUpdate", "2022-05-02 12:53:00");
        Call<EnviarUno> userCall = api.postUno(paramObject.toString());
        userCall.enqueue((Callback<EnviarUno>) this);
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void onResponse(Call<EnviarUno> call, Response<EnviarUno> response) {
    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Conectado pero con error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Información enviada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void onFailure(Call<EnviarUno> call, Throwable t) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

La interfaz quedó de la siguiente manera:

```
public interface API {
    @Headers({"Content-Type: application/json"})
    @POST("PruebaGP")
    Call<EnviarUno> postUno(@Body String jsonobject);
}
```

y el constructor así:

```
public class EnviarUno {
    public String IdRow;
    public String Nombre;
    public String FecUpdate;

    public EnviarUno(String IdRow, String Nombre, String FecUpdate) {
        this.IdRow = IdRow;
        this.Nombre = Nombre;
        this.FecUpdate = FecUpdate;
}
```

Uno de los problemas que también encontré es que todas las implementaciones que estaba viendo eran para versiones pasadas de retrofit, esta implementación es para las versiones más recientes (en este ejemplo estoy usando la versión 2.9.0)...

Espero les sirva. Gracias a los que comentaron la respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Para los que no encuentren el error, igual yo tenía un error idéntico y aunque probé todo no se solucionaba, el error venía del API (si es que ustedes la diseñaron), el método POST al que se llama debe darles como respuesta un JSON de forma String, así lo resolví en mi caso:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> AddKid(Kids kid)
    {
        _context.Kids.Add(kid);
    var x=await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        if (x > 0)
        {
            return "{\"respuesta\":\"200\"}";
        }
        return "{\"respuesta\":\"9999\"}";
                 
        //return CreatedAtAction("GetKid", new { id = kid.id });
    }
```

cuando antes tenía algo así:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> AddKid(Kids kid)
    {
        _context.Kids.Add(kid);
    var x=await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        if (x > 0)
        {
            return "200";
        }
        return "9999";
                 
        //return CreatedAtAction("GetKid", new { id = kid.id });
    }
```